# HTML textarea : change the string dropped (when drag and drop)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have simply two things in my HTML:

```
<img src="/img/something.jpg">
<textarea></textarea>
```

When I do a Drag and Drop of the image from the textarea, I have in my textarea the value: "/img/something.jpg".

I want to change this value when I do a Drag and Drop, but I don't know how.

For exemple, when I do a Drag and Drop of the image to the textarea, I want 
"[img]/img/something.jpg[/img]" in.

I can use HTML5, JavaScript and AngularJS, but no jQuery...

Thank's for your help ! :)

Comment: What's your question? What did you try? Did you look at Drag and Drop HTML5 tutorials? I know people tend to be against w3schools, but here is a good example of doing that: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp basically you use `e.target.appendChild(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution... But http://jsfiddle.net/ydj8Lg8a/1/

```
var dropbox = document.getElementById('myTextarea');
dropbox.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);

function drop(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault(); 
  document.getElementById('hidden').innerHTML = evt.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
  this.value += '[img]' + document.getElementById('hidden').childNodes[0].src + '[/img]';
}
```